# Entity translation: views with and without language fallback

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I need views with entity language fallback and others without.

if "Enable language fallback" is activated, is there a way to disable this for a specific view

Thanks
Rainer

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a solution with "Enable language fallback" activated. I guess it has to be made the other way around. Disabling it and add a fallback on views level using the "No results behavior".